# ExecutionEngineException with SQL and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

My code is trying to load from a database using LINQ to SQL. At the moment as soon as i seem to touch what a query returns i get a crash with the error ExecutionExceptionError occured:

[image: problem]

Currently my code is very simple, i have a standard dbml class that is meant to load a single table MC:

```
 private void RibbonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MultipleChoiceDataContext t = new MultipleChoiceDataContext();
        var test =
            from a in t.GetTable<MC>()
            select a;

        testbox.Content = test.First().question;
    }
```

The error takes place on the line of

> test.First().question;

I cannot find any help in the area or someone who has experienced this problem before, so i'm hoping someone may have an idea of how to fix this

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your entity model?

Comment: Certainly have. Nothing happening there

Comment: Also try changing query syntax to var q = t.MCs.FirstOrDefault(); if (q!= null) testbox.Content = q.Question;

Comment: Just tried, that. It comes up with the same problem

Comment: The View Detail link is there for a reason :)

Comment: It has very little data, in fact the data field in view details is empty, help link is null, inner exception is null and source is null. It weirdly seems to provide no extra information at all

Comment: Try to re-create your dbml. If you are on SQL server launch profiler and see what activities are going on when you execute the LINQ query.

Comment: Recreating doesn't seem to do anything, finding the profiler now

Comment: And the trace finds no activities are going on on the server. This is so weird

Comment: Have you applied all recent VS patches?

Comment: Run your exe in another computer and see what happens.

Comment: Got it working, posted how below

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutionEngineException` indicates an internal problem to the CLR. It means one of the following:

1. You used unsafe code or PInvoke to cause memory corruption. The CLR's data structures are now corrupt.
2. Some other library did this (a bug).
3. A bug in the CLR itself.

In all cases the solution is to work around the issue, maybe by changing things randomly until the application unbreaks. Try refactoring your code, comment out stuff until the error disappears. Factor things out into new methods. Think whether a library you are using might be doing unsafe stuff. Maybe the stack trace can tell you what functionality to avoid.

This is a deeply unmethodical approach but the best that I know of. Very hard to work around because you did nothing specific wrong. In particular, the line of code that you showed cannot normally cause memory corruption.

Comment: Well at the moment, at the moment it seems to be coming from accessing the test.First() part. That's the only section of code that's actually seeming to do anything. Currently been only working on this for about 30 minutes without adding any other libraries so i'm unsure how i would have managed 1 or 2

Comment: Looks like a problem in System.Transactions. This assembly uses unsafe code, PInvoke and COM interop. Try creating a very small repro project and try it on another computer. Maybe you'll find that something on your installation is corrupted.

Comment: If my installation was corrupted is there a way i can reinstall .NET and required DLL's without reinstalling the whole visual studio?

Comment: It certainly seems to happen on any version of .NET i have installed on this computer, still to check on another

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the problem was due to the installation of the preview of Visual Studio 2013, upon uninstalling that, the solution worked perfectly again on Visual Studio 2012

Thanks for all the help!